# arrow/python/platform.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cython, apache-arrow

Iam using apache arrow with C++ and Iam using cython to make an interface between some of the C++ function and python

when I try to build the setup file I get this error message :
arrow/python/platform.h: No such file or directory

I have apache arrow installed and indeed arrow/python/platform.h doesn't exist

```
# distutils: language=c++

from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name="cpp_ext",
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        Extension(
            "cpp_ext", ["cpp_ext/module.pyx"],
            extra_compile_args=["-O3"],
            extra_link_args=["-larrow"],
             include_dirs=["/usr/include/arrow"],
            language="c++",
        ),
    ),
)
```

is there a way to install apache arrow so that I get arrow/python/platform.h

Comment: Most Linux distributions put headers and other stuff that is only used for compiling custom code into a separate "devel" packet. For example if you installed arrow as package "apache-arrow", check whether there is a package "apache-arrow-devel"

Comment: @Homer512 I tried to install it as package I got this error :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-arrow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-arrow

Comment: Two things: 1. You're not giving nearly enough information to help with that, such as your linux distribution, package manager, etc. 2. Stack Overflow is for programming issues, not linux system management. You should ask on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or a distribution-specific channel such as [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)